# Diferença entre AddMvc vs AddMvcCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Em alguns exemplos que tenho acompanhado, tenho encontrado duas chamadas no `Startup` de aplicações em `asp.net-core`

**AddMvc:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
}
```

**AddMvcCore:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
}
```

- Quais seriam suas diferenças?
- Quando utilizar um ou outro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenho começado a mexer com `asp.net-core`e fiquei curioso com a pergunta. Olhando a doc e o código fonte, temos as duas chamadas com os seguintes código:

**TL;DR:**
O `AddMvc` implementa mais itens que o `AddMvcCore`, que por sua vez implementa apenas o "básico".

**AddMvc:**

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddMvc(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    var builder = services.AddMvcCore();

    builder.AddApiExplorer();
    builder.AddAuthorization();

    AddDefaultFrameworkParts(builder.PartManager);

    builder.AddFormatterMappings();
    builder.AddViews();
    builder.AddRazorViewEngine();
    builder.AddCacheTagHelper();

    builder.AddDataAnnotations(); // +1 order

    builder.AddJsonFormatters();

    builder.AddCors();

    return new MvcBuilder(builder.Services, builder.PartManager);
}
```

**AddMvcCore**

```
public static IMvcCoreBuilder AddMvcCore(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (services == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
    }

    var partManager = GetApplicationPartManager(services);
    services.TryAddSingleton(partManager);

    ConfigureDefaultFeatureProviders(partManager);
    ConfigureDefaultServices(services);
    AddMvcCoreServices(services);

    var builder = new MvcCoreBuilder(services, partManager);

    return builder;
}
```

- O `AddMvc` é um método "maior", porque além de chamar o `"core"`, chama `AddJsonFormatters()`, `AddCacheTagHelper()`, `AddRazorViewEngine()`, `AddViews()` e `AddFormatterMappings()`.
- O `AddMvcCore` é bem mais curto pois chama apenas os itens básico.

Quando é usado o `AddMvcCore` todos itens como, formatação de `json`, `razor`, tratamento de `cache` e etc, devem ser adicionados "na mão". Uma forma de fazer isso seria `services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters()`.

Sobre quando usar um e quando não usar outro. (baseado em opinião) Tudo depende de qual aplicação se está desenvolvendo, há necessidade de na "raiz" do sistema vir implementado itens como `razor`, `json formater` ou é uma aplicação que não fará utilização desses itens?.

<sub>obs: talvez essa resposta sobre quando usar não agrade</sub>